# How to just use only one rule in yara rules file?

Tags: c, malware, yara

In a yara rules file-`malware.yar`, content like

```
rule rules_one 
{}
rule rules_two
{}
...
```

there are many rule in the file, I use `yr_compiler_add_file` to add file, then use `yr_compiler_get_rules` to get rules. I get all rules from the rules file, now I just want to use one rule to scan buffer.

If I use `yr_rules_scan_mem`, it will scan buffer with all rules. but I just only need one to do this. How can I do?